# JS check if value exist in space seperated values

Tags: javascript

I have a space separated values `80,3537,3718,3721, 1519, 2344` and i want to check if the second value matches any of the space separated values

For example if the second value equals any of the following 3 then the output should be pass

- `80,3537,3718,3721`
- `1519`
- `2344`

The following value should fail because it does not match any of the space seperated values

`2000`

I want to achieve this in plain javascript, how can this be done.

UPDATE:

This is what i tried so far to check if `result2` exist in `result1` space separated values

```
var result1 = '80,3537,3718,3721, 1519, 2344'
var result2 = '1519'

    if (result1.match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)" + result2 + "(?:,|$)"))) {
        console.log(true);            
    }
```

Comment: second value is 3537?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain the second value is `1519` because its seperated by space not comma

Comment: `indexOf(...)` should do it, eg: `numbers.indexOf(" " + searchedNumber) != -1`. You may also want to check if `searchedNumber` has a comma after it or it is at the end.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question shows no sign of effort.

Comment: what do you need as result? the position of just `true`/`false`?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes just true false will do

Comment: This is not a valid JS line `var result1 = 80,3537,3718,3721, 1519, 2344`.

Comment: Your code should work, you just need to add a space before `result2`

Comment: @Titus that was really helpful but the problem with that is it does not take the first value into consideration because the first value is not seperated by space

Comment: @Saadia Can you also give a valid case? And what should happen for `80,3537,3718,3721, 1519, 2344,1519`?

Comment: Short answer: if ( result1.split(', ').includes(result2) ) console.log(true);

Comment: In that case, try: `new RegExp("(?:(^|,\s))" + resut2 + "(?:,|$)")`

Comment: @Titus would you like to post this as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex needs a slight modification in order for it to cover all the possible cases.

```js
var result1 = "80,3537,3718,3721, 1519, 2344";
var result2 = "1519";
if (new RegExp("(^|(,\\s))" + result2 + "(,|$)").test(result1)) {
    console.log(true);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a little helper function. I don't see any code to get more specific, but this should work fine.

```js
function checkVal(str, val) {
  const arr = str.split(' ');
  return arr.includes(val);
}

//For Example...


let exStr = '132,340,23 32 345 1,223',
    exVal = '345';
    
alert(checkVal(exStr, exVal));
```

(Edit)

Using your variables, it would look like this. I added a space and comma to the split to match the ', ' you have between each value in your example.

```js
var result1 = '80,3537,3718,3721, 1519, 2344';
var result2 = '1519';

var test = result1.split(', ').includes(result2);
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the space separated string first.

```
var secondNumber = whatever;
var string = "80,3537,3718,3721, 1519, 2344";
var ans = string.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
    num = ans[i];
    num.replace(/,/g , "");
    num = parseInt(num, 10);
}
if (ans.indexOf(secondNumber) > -1 ) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Using for in on array is  a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '80,3537,3718,3721, 1519, 2344';
var arr = str.split(' ');
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i].trim().replace(/,\s*$/, "");
}
console.log((arr.indexOf('1519') === 1)?'true':'false');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.